# Does iter_messages ignore some type of messages by default?

Tags: python, telethon

In short, iter_messages returned all messages under a TG channel post, but did not include a message with multiple photos attached. So I assume it ignored it because it's a different type of message, not a text or photo message, but a message with a collection of photos. Is that a different type, ignored by default? I'm using Telethon version 1.30.3

From what I can tell, iter_messages accepts a Union which includes TypeMessagesFilter which in turn includes types such as InputMessagesFilterPhotos. Not too sure if this type of message with photos + caption is included as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter it to only photos, and see if it makes a difference:

```
# Filter by message type:
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterPhotos
async for message in client.iter_messages(chat, filter=InputMessagesFilterPhotos):
    print(message.photo)
```

Comment: The way this question was asked, the asker is trying to understand the default operation of the system, not how they could apply their own filtering. If they need all, unfiltered data, this won't get them to their goal.